# Could not find resource /com/example/demoMyBatis/XML/Student.xml

Tags: spring

i got a simple mybatis implement and 2 xml file 1 for mapper and 1 for sqlmapconfig.Somehow when i run it keep showing error Could not find resource /com/example/demoMyBatis/XML/Student.xml. been try to find solution like resource filterring but nothing work.pls help

**SqlMapConfig.xml**

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">

<configuration>
    <typeAliases>
        <typeAlias alias="Student" type="com.example.demoMyBatis.XML.Student"/>
    </typeAliases>

    <environments default="development">
        <environment id="development">
            <transactionManager type="JDBC" />
            <dataSource type="POOLED">
                <property name="driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
                <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mybatis" />
                <property name="username" value="root" />
                <property name="password" value="12345678" />
            </dataSource>
        </environment>
    </environments>

    <mappers>
        <mapper resource="/com/example/demoMyBatis/XML/Student.xml" />
    </mappers>
</configuration>
```

**Student.xml**

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"  "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">

<mapper namespace="Student">
    <insert id="insertStudent" parameterType="Student" >
        INSERT INTO STUDENT (ID, NAME, BRANCH, PERCENTAGE, PHONE, EMAIL ) VALUES (#{id}, #{name}, #{branch}, #{percentage}, #{phone}, #{email});
    </insert>

    <update id="updateStudent" parameterType="Student">
        UPDATE STUDENT SET EMAIL = #{email}, NAME = #{name}, BRANCH = #{branch}, PERCENTAGE = #{percentage}, PHONE = #{phone} WHERE ID = #{id};
    </update>

    <delete id="deleteStudentById" parameterType="int">
        DELETE from STUDENT WHERE ID = #{id};
    </delete>

    <select id="selectAllStudent" resultType="Student">
        SELECT * FROM STUDENT;
    </select>

    <select id="selectStudentById" parameterType="int" resultType="Student">
        SELECT * FROM STUDENT WHERE ID = #{id};
    </select>

    <resultMap id = "result" type = "Student">
        <result property = "id" column = "ID"/>
        <result property = "name" column = "NAME"/>
        <result property = "branch" column = "BRANCH"/>
        <result property = "percentage" column = "PERCENTAGE"/>
        <result property = "phone" column = "PHONE"/>
        <result property = "email" column = "EMAIL"/>
    </resultMap>
</mapper>
```

**POM.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demoMyBatis-XML</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demoMyBatis-XML</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                </includes>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                </includes>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is modified code according to [this](https://www.springcloud.io/post/2022-03/springboot-mybatis-mysql/) tutorial.

1. Changed mapper namespace to: com.example.mybatisdemo.mapper.StudentMapper
2. Changed mapper name to student-mapper.xml
3. put student-mapper.xml into src/main/resources/mapper folder

```xml
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"  "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">

<mapper namespace="com.example.mybatisdemo.mapper.StudentMapper">

    <insert id="insertStudent" parameterType="Student" >
        INSERT INTO STUDENT (ID, NAME, BRANCH, PERCENTAGE, PHONE, EMAIL ) VALUES (#{id}, #{name}, #{branch}, #{percentage}, #{phone}, #{email});
    </insert>

    <update id="updateStudent" parameterType="Student">
        UPDATE STUDENT SET EMAIL = #{email}, NAME = #{name}, BRANCH = #{branch}, PERCENTAGE = #{percentage}, PHONE = #{phone} WHERE ID = #{id};
    </update>

    <delete id="deleteStudentById" parameterType="int">
        DELETE from STUDENT WHERE ID = #{id};
    </delete>

    <select id="selectAllStudents" resultType="Student">
        SELECT * FROM STUDENT;
    </select>

    <select id="selectStudentById" parameterType="int" resultType="Student">
        SELECT * FROM STUDENT WHERE ID = #{id};
    </select>

    <resultMap id = "result" type = "Student">
        <result property = "id" column = "ID"/>
        <result property = "name" column = "NAME"/>
        <result property = "branch" column = "BRANCH"/>
        <result property = "percentage" column = "PERCENTAGE"/>
        <result property = "phone" column = "PHONE"/>
        <result property = "email" column = "EMAIL"/>
    </resultMap>
</mapper>
```

4. Created com.example.mybatisdemo.mapper.StudentMapper interface:

```
@Mapper
public interface StudentMapper {
    void insertStudent(Student student);
    void updateStudent(Student student);
    void deleteStudentById(int id);
    List<Student> selectAllStudents();
    Student selectStudentById(int id);
}
```

5. Created com.example.mybatisdemo.dao.Student pojo with lombok:

```
@Data
public class Student {
    Integer id;
    String name;
    String branch;
    Integer percentage;
    Integer phone;
    String email;
}
```

6. Populated config with properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mybatis
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=12345678
mybatis.mapper-locations=classpath:mapper/**/*-mapper.xml
mybatis.type-aliases-package=com.example.mybatisdemo.dao
logging.level.com.example.mybatisdemo.mapper=DEBUG
```

pom.xml does not contain build/resources section because xml mappers are used from resources (not src) folder. I haven't checked the possibility to put xml mappers to src folder.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the file `Student.xml` lies in folder `src/main/resources/com/example/demoMyBatis/XML/` within your project in IDE Eclipse/ intelliJ/ whatever.